# Python writerows only writes the last row of NLTK FreqDist to a csv file

Tags: python, csv, nltk

I have been writing Python code to find the frequency distribution of words contained in a text document using words contained in a Python list (`word_list`) The program calculates the frequency distribution and I can print them to the screen, but when I attempt to write the frequency distribution to a .csv file it only writes the last row of `FreqDist` repeatedly for however many text files are in the directory. My code is as follows

```
CIK_List = []


for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(test_path, '*.txt')):

 CIK = re.search(r"\_([0-9]+)\_", filename) # extract the CIK from the filename

 path = nltk.data.find(filename)
 raw = open(path, 'r').read()

 tokens = word_tokenize(raw)
 words = [h.lower() for h in tokens]
 f_dist = nltk.FreqDist([s.lower() for s in words])
 print(f_dist)

 wordcount = collections.Counter()

 CIK_List.append(CIK) 
 with open(file_path, 'w+', newline= '') as csv_file:
  writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
  writer.writerow(["CIK"] + word_list)
  for m in word_list:
    print([CIK.group(1)], [f_dist[m]], end='')

  for val in CIK_List:
     writer.writerows(([val.group(1)] + [f_dist[m] for m in word_list],))
```

Comment: Your code isn't complete as you haven't defined `CIK_List` anywhere.  And where does `filename` come from?  Is this whole block of code within a loop, something along the lines of `for filename in ...:` ?  Please edit your question and include all of the code necessary to reproduce the problem.  If your code isn't complete, we might try to fill in the gaps ourselves, get that wrong and write an unhelpful answer for you.

Comment: I've added the extra code fragments as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that for every input file you read, you create the output file and write the

Take a look at the following loop at the end of the code.  What does it do?

```py
  for val in CIK_List:
     writer.writerows(([val.group(1)] + [f_dist[m] for m in word_list],))
```

`CIK_List` is a list of regexp matches.  For each such regexp match, we write out the first matching group (which is the numeric part of the filename), and then we write out *something that does not depend on `val`*.  So as `val` runs through the list of regexp matches, you get the same output time and time again.

You are also opening the file several times, once per input file, and every time you open the file, you throw away the contents that were there previously.

What you probably want to do is to open the output file once, write out the header row, and then, for each input file, write a single row to the output file based on the contents of that input file:

```py
CIK_List = []
with open(file_path, 'w+', newline= '') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow(["CIK"] + word_list)

    for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(test_path, '*.txt')):

        CIK = re.search(r"\_([0-9]+)\_", filename) # extract the CIK from the filename

        path = nltk.data.find(filename)
        raw = open(path, 'r').read()
        
        tokens = word_tokenize(raw)
        words = [h.lower() for h in tokens]
        f_dist = nltk.FreqDist([s.lower() for s in words])
        print(f_dist)
        
        wordcount = collections.Counter()

        CIK_List.append(CIK) 
        for m in word_list:
            print([CIK.group(1)], [f_dist[m]], end='')

        writer.writerow([CIK.group(1)] + [f_dist[m] for m in word_list])
```

Comment: Hi Luke, I tried this on a small data set and it works completely.  I've run it on a larger sample of text files contained in a directory (> 70000) and it processed most of them l before I ended the program.  I see your point concerning the positioning of the open file statement,  but why would the correct distribution details for the CIK, not simply be written in the same row as the "val" variable which is simply an append of CIK, unless the repeated opening of the .csv file over-wrote it?

Comment: @DaleAddison: the repeated opening of the CSV file does overwrite it, as I wrote in my answer.  You could try modifying your original code by opening the file in append mode, by replacing `w+` with `a+`, and you'd see all the data your code wrote to the file which got overwritten.  Only run this on a small dataset, though: running it on 70,000 files would generate a CSV file with over 2 billion rows.